# startup project for learning mongo db

Tags: mongodb

I want to learn **mongodb**.

what could be a simple project as a start to learn MONGODB??

Please provide your views.

Thank You.

Comment: If you can't image of a project then you don't need a database.

Answer (score 4):

Check 10gen's websites (mongodb.org and 10gen.com) for tutorials and use cases. Either of these might be good to start with:
https://www.10gen.com/presentations/mongodb-stockholm/2012/building-your-first-mongodb-application
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-a-tumblelog-application-with-django-mongodb-engine/